# Hide Payment method Information when product price is zero in Magento

Tags: magento, checkout

in my magento there products with zero price.

When checkout that products i want to hide the `Payment method Information`.

that is this is the screen shot of check out steps:

[image]

the 4th step need to be hide when the product price is 0.

How can i do this?

In normal case that means if the product have price value greater than zero ,then it displays all 1 to 5 steps.

But i need here is that if the product price is zero doesnot display the 4th step.

Comment: This is not easy to achive, you want to remove one step from the onepagecheckout. What you can do easily is to add the "Zero Subtotal Checkout", so the user gets a new payment option to pay nothing and don't have to insert his payment data. You can find this under: System > Configuration > Payment Methods > Zero Subtotal Checkout

Answer (score 3):

In admin panel,

System -> Configuration -> SALES -> Payment Methods

enable the Zero Subtotal Checkout method.

It'll take care of it automatically.

But if you wanna skip that step completely

additionally check for the subtotal in onepage controller
and if it is zero just change the next step flag.

Answer (score 1):

i've done it once but already forgot,

**step 1:** First get configured Flat Rate and Payment MEthod Paypal from Admin Panel.

**step 2:**  app/code/core/mage/checkout/block/onepage.php

change $stepCodes with

```
$stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'review');
```

**step3:**  app/code/core/mage/checkout/controller/Onepagecontrollers.php

change the saveShippingMethod function

**step 4:** opcheckout.js

this is useful links from 
[this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/76049/) and 
[this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/76049/)

Comment: @Marcel Chrisanothe ,the `payment method` is not displaying in all cases.I need it to hide when subtotal is `0`.It is need to display when subtotal is greater than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try what they say in [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/76049/) link.

What they do is jump over steps automatically. But, if you want to jump over a step, it needs to have a default value.

I haven't tried to do exactly what you need, but I guess maybe what you need is to modify **opcheckout.js** and check there if your price is 0. If it's 0, then you auto assign a payment method that you will ignore and jump to the next step.

I think I would try something like that...